# Where can I find the Ubuntu dock icon

Tags: gnome, launcher, icons

Im looking for the location of the Ubuntu starter icon (or whatever the name of this icon is), the very top one in the starter menu. After looking up on Google i only found tutorials for changing single program icons or icon themes, which is not what I am looking for, since the Ubuntu-starter-icon is not theme dependant.

Thank you in advance

Comment: nevermind, problem solved!

Comment: If you've solved it, please be so kind as to write up an answer so that others with the same issue can benefit. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found is:

On **Ubuntu 16.04** the icon is located in

```
/usr/share/unity/icons/launcher_bfb.png
```

Resolution of the icon is (or has to be) **54x54** pixel

*Don't forget to back up the original before replacing*

Answer (score 0):

Some people seem to be referring to it as the "Gnome-Panel" icon, while others call it the "start-here" icon.
I believe [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=920284) may be what you are looking for, though.

**NOTE: I am currently running CentOS and am not near a Ubuntu box to test this. Proceed at your own risk and please report back your findings. Also save and close anything with files open, in case you need to force a restart.**

To prevent dead linking:

- Backup and replace the file at `/usr/share/icons/themename/24x24/places/start_here.png`. The post says it needs to be 24x24 but this may change over time. I would recommend you match whatever size icon is already there.
- Update the cache with `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Human/`
- Restart Gnome Panel weith `killall gnome-panel`